# Disable submit if inputs empty - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Whine I submit empty form it insert an empty raw to my database. I am using CodeIgniter form validation also. How can I avoid this using CodeIgniter . Help Me Please.  ex- If from is empty no from submission.

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
    // validate name
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    // validate email
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone Number', 'trim|required|min_length[10]|max_length[10]');
    // validate phone number
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Questions or Comments', 'required|min_length[10]');
    // validate phone number
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)// if from validation failed load following pages from views
    {
        $this->load->view('template/header.php');
        $this->load->view('pages/contacts');
        $this->load->view('template/footer.php');
    }
    else // if from validation success load following pages from views
    {
        $this->load->view('template/header.php');
        $data['result']="Thank you for contacting us! We will reply you soon... ";
        $this->load->view('pages/contacts',$data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer.php');
    }
```

I am using required validation rule too please help me to fix this

```
<?php echo form_open('form/contact') ?><!--Creates an opening form
        ex :<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="localhost/index.php/form(controller)/subscribe(function)" />-->
        <!-- Contact form Start -->
        <div class="span7">
            <div class="box">
                <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="notice marker-on-bottom bg-darkRed fg-white" id="bottom_form_error">', '</div>'); ?>
                    <?php if(isset($result)){echo '<div class="notice marker-on-bottom  bg-green fg-white">'.$result.'</div>';}?>
                    <!-- Display Validation error massages  -->
                <h6>*All fields marked are required</h6>
                    <lable>Your name*</lable>
                    <div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" placeholder="type your name">
                        <button class="btn-clear" tabindex="-1"></button>
                    </div>
                    <lable>Email*</lable>
                    <div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" placeholder="type email address">
                        <button class="btn-clear" tabindex="-1"></button>
                    </div>
                    <lable>Phone*</lable>
                    <div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">
                        <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo set_value('phone'); ?>" placeholder="type phone number">
                        <button class="btn-clear" tabindex="-1"></button>
                    </div>
                    <lable>Questions or Comments*</lable>
                    <div class="input-control textarea" data-role="input-control">
                        <textarea name="comment" value="<?php echo set_value('comment'); ?>" >...</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input name='contactus_status' type='hidden' value='no'/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="info">
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php  echo form_close(); ?><!-- Contact form End -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for **required** of Codeigniter Server Side Validation

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
```

Complete Documentation [Form validation codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

If you want Client Side validation [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Here is [<kbd>Sample Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/myn4K/1/) of Jquery Form Validation

Comment: i am using required validation I updated the post with the code.

Comment: Post your html **Form** Code. and don't forgot to **Include** library. `$this->load->library('form_validation');`

Comment: I posted the html form. $this->load->library('form_validation') loaded from autoload.php

Comment: Code looks fine for now. Where is code of inserting data??? means where you are calling function of modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent actual submit only on client side with JavaScript, however with that approach you cannot be sure form is not submitted (because one can mess with client side script). Instead you must validate submitted values.

Answer (score 0):

I seems your MySQL code is outside the if else statement of the validation. Be sure to put it in the right place.

Here's the missing data on your sample.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

}else{
    // Be sure to put your database insert code here...
    $data['name'] = set_value('name');
    $data['email'] = set_value('email');
    $data['phone'] = set_value('phone');
    $data['comment'] = set_value('comment');
    $this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
}
```